# how to match rules using regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to regex stuff in C#. I am not sure how to use the regex to validate client reference number. This client reference number has 3 different types : id, mobile number, and serial number.

C#:

```
string client = "ABC 1234567891233";

//do code stuff here:
if Regex matches 3-4 digits to client, return value = client id
else if Regex matches 8 digts to client, return value = ref no
else if Regex matches 13 digits to client, return value = phone no
```

I dont know how to count digits using Regex for different types. Like Regex("{![\d.....}").

Comment: Have you searched for digit counting in regex c#? Also if you have only this 3 types just count number of characters in string -> `yourMagicString.Length` and check number

Comment: Just match for digits and then decide by `value.Length`?

Comment: @Prix it depends on length. if client no length is 13, goes to mobile. can identify different digits.

Comment: This is really some basic quantifiers knowledge. We won't use `\\d` since it may match other digits (in other languages). So `[0-9]` will match one digit. `[0-9]{5,9}` will match 5 to 9 digits, `[0-9]{10}` will match 10 digits, now guess the regex for the mobile number. From now on it's just a matter of using if/else statements. You may add ^$ to the expression to define begin/end of line(string?).

Comment: @HamZa: put that in as an answer rather than a comment. It seems pretty complete.

Comment: Why do you insist on using (solely) a regex? It doesn't look like a right tool for the job here

Comment: Start learning regex [in general](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), [the hard way*](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/) and [in java specifically](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html). * It isn't hard at all :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you're bent on using regular expressions here. A simple one-liner would do, eg. even such an extension method:

```
static int NumbersCount(this string str)
{
    return str.ToCharArray().Where(c => Char.IsNumber(c)).Count();
}
```

It's clearer and more maintainable in my opinion.

You could probably give it a go with group matching and something along the lines of

```
"(?<client>[0-9]{5,9}?)|(?<serial>[0-9]{10}?)|(?<mobile>[0-9]{13,}?)"
```

Then you'd check whether you have a match for "client", "serial", "mobile" and interpret the string input on that basis. But is it easier to understand?

Does it express your intentions more clearly for those reading your code later on?

If the requirement is such that these numbers must be consecutive (as @Corak points out)... I'd still write that iteratively, like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// returns lengths of all the numeric sequences encountered in the string
/// </summary>        
static IEnumerable<int> Lengths(string str)
{
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Char.IsNumber(str[i]))
        {
            count++;
        }
        if ((!Char.IsNumber(str[i]) || i == str.Length - 1) && count > 0)
        {
            yield return count;                
            count = 0;                    
        }
    }
}
```

And then you could simply:

```
bool IsClientID(string str)
{
    var lenghts = Lengths(str);
    return lenghts.Count() == 1 && lenghts.Single() == 5;            
}
```

Is it more verbose? Yes, but chances are that people will still like you more than if you make them fiddling with regex every time the validation rules happen to change, or some debugging is required : ) This includes your future self.

Comment: If you have filtered out cases like `"a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8"` beforehand, yes, this looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question. But if you want to get the number of Numerical Characters from a string you can use the following code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+$");
string ValidateString = regex.Replace(ValidateString, "");
if(ValidateString.Length > 4 && ValidateString.Length < 10)
    //this is a customer id
....
```

Comment: thanks it is almost what i am looking for but i want the regex to count digits to return value....

Comment: Will this not cause problems if your validate string is "a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8" since it will strip out all the non numeric and then identify it as a customerid which is probably not correct...

Comment: yes right, @Chris , i have already validation for this. It would validate string first before counting digits to identify a type of client.

Comment: I dont know how to count digits using Regex for different types

Comment: @user1358072: There are string methods to give you a length, why do you need regex if your validation is already done?